# How do you play a long audio clip on Alexa / Amazon Echo?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I couldn't find anything in the Alexa Skills Kit (ASK) documentation that allows a developer to tell Alexa to play a long (90+ seconds) audio clip.

How do you get the Echo to play a long MP3 file?

The [SSML audio](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#audio) tag allows you to play an MP3 file, but it's limited to 90 seconds, and has to be 48 kbps-encoded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon has released new ASK features and long form audio is now possible.  Check out the announcement and documentation:  https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills#